# Chromium causes high Xorg CPU usage

Tags: xorg, google-chrome, chromium, cpu-load

As said in the title, often `Chromium` causes a high load because of `Xorg` using between 50%-90% of CPU. 
It happens without any evident pattern (maybe it's related to the pinned tabs, but I'm not too sure) and I'm forced to close all the opened windows to lower the CPU usage. What is even more strange is the fact that reopening the same windows doesn't cause an high CPU usage again (`Xorg` remains between 1% and 6%)

I'm using `Chromium 47.0.2526.73` for `Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)`

Comment: Does this happen with other browsers?

Comment: @SuperSluether don't know, really. While I have other browsers installed, I mostly use `Chromium`. Also, because there are no reproducible steps, I don't know how to check.

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same issue with 64-bit trusty and Chrome (not Chromium). I'm running i3 WM, might be relevant.

Comment: I'm having this issue with Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu Yakkety.  It's really weird, since the CPU usage is on the Xorg process, but clears up as soon as I kill certain chromium windows.  Some chromium windows don't cause this, others do.  I'm using the proprietary nvidia driver, and I'm not sure if it's related.